# how to print formatted output to printer in java standalone application

Tags: java, printing

Basically i m creating a java standalone application where a student first gives his entire details.

when the print button is clicked i want to print some of the data given by the student in a specified format

like:

```
//logo goes here


                         regn no:
                         regn date:
name:
phnno:
mail:
```

how to do it??

Comment: i have already implemented the database connectivity part. now i just want to print these specific information in specific format

Comment: Well yes, and what have you coded for this latter part?

Comment: @fge that is my problem. i dont knw how to do that

Comment: Well, you can have a look at `Formatter`

Comment: @darijan that cmd prints to standard output that's not my requirement

Comment: no there shoul be some other soln for it

Comment: Then list your requirements. And do have a look at `Formatter`.

Comment: i listed out all my requirements. I have my data . i just want that when the print button(which is a jbutton i created) will be clicked the data should be printed out in the specified format as described in the question

Comment: that should be printed out through printer

Answer (score 3):

If you want to do printing with Java with any kind of formatting instead of plain text, you need to use `javax.print`.  It is quite similar to the 2D graphics.

Have a look at the official tutorial at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/printing/ to learn how to do it.

From http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/displayCode.html?code=http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/printing/examples/HelloWorldPrinter.java (untested):

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.print.*;

public class HelloWorldPrinter implements Printable, ActionListener {


    public int print(Graphics g, PageFormat pf, int page) throws
                                                        PrinterException {

        if (page > 0) { /* We have only one page, and 'page' is zero-based */
            return NO_SUCH_PAGE;
        }

        /* User (0,0) is typically outside the imageable area, so we must
         * translate by the X and Y values in the PageFormat to avoid clipping
         */
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g;
        g2d.translate(pf.getImageableX(), pf.getImageableY());

        /* Now we perform our rendering */
        g.drawString("Hello world!", 100, 100);

        /* tell the caller that this page is part of the printed document */
        return PAGE_EXISTS;
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
         PrinterJob job = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
         job.setPrintable(this);
         boolean ok = job.printDialog();
         if (ok) {
             try {
                  job.print();
             } catch (PrinterException ex) {
              /* The job did not successfully complete */
             }
         }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        UIManager.put("swing.boldMetal", Boolean.FALSE);
        JFrame f = new JFrame("Hello World Printer");
        f.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
           public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {System.exit(0);}
        });
        JButton printButton = new JButton("Print Hello World");
        printButton.addActionListener(new HelloWorldPrinter());
        f.add("Center", printButton);
        f.pack();
        f.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```